# Short story about a city shaped like a horse, man hunts for third eye

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

So the story is sort of post apocalyptic in that there is an entire city that for some reason is living in a (spaceship?) shaped like a horse. 
The main character is a man with a wife and teenage son. The guy is weird. At one point he says,

> call me (something) call me (something) but don’t call me late to
>   dinner!

I don’t remember why but for some reason this man believes there is a third eye of the horse and I think you can see outside from it. He goes on a mission to find the third eye.

This story is weird as heck but I can’t stop thinking about it and really want to read it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microscopic people that live inside a person?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183420/microscopic-people-that-live-inside-a-person)

Comment: I've voted to leave this question open. It should be closed the other way, the answer here is _far_ better than the other answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Jonathan Lethem’s *[This Shape We’re In](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32079.This_Shape_We_re_In)*.

> Lethem, author of the bestselling Motherless Brooklyn , returns in
>   concentrated form - packing twice the adventure into one-eighth the
>   pages. This book could be some kind of allegory book, but it might not
>   be an allegory book at all. It involves people and drinking and people
>   looking for a giant eye. It is among the best things Mr. Lethem has
>   written.

There's a review [here](http://www.steelypips.org/library/0203.html#022003) that gives some additional detail, mentioning the spaceship (of indeterminate form) and the quest for the third eye.

> The book concerns the activities of Henry Farbur, a cretinous drunk of
>   an Everyman who lives in the bizarre world inside a Shape of somewhat
>   indeterminate biological form-- Henry and his wife have a burrow in
>   the bowels, while there's a cathedral in the left lung, and so on. The
>   purpose of the shape is a subject for much speculation among the
>   inhabitants-- religions have sprung up asserting that it's a bomb
>   shelter, or a generation starship, or something else entirely.
>
> There's some snappy writing here, as Henry and his stooge Balkan
>   embark on a quest to find the third eye, with Henry abusing everyone
>   he encounters verbally and otherwise. The final revelation of the
>   purpose of the Shape and the red phones from Central Command was
>   unexpected and clever, which counts for something, but I'm still not
>   entirely sure what the point of the whole thing was.

Comment: I can't find a copy of *This Shape We-re In* but in Amnesia Moon Lethem has the phrase *"Call me Edge,” Kellogg parroted. “Call me Ishmael. Call me anything, but don’t call me late for dinner."*

Comment: @JohnRennie - Interesting. He may have recycled the joke or OP might have some kind of anthology.

Comment: Right on, thank you!

Comment: @Invisiblallama - Don't forget to upvote and mark this is "accepted" using the little tick on the left.

Comment: done! - sorry this was my first post